# BigQuery : Data processed when running Select on Custom Partitioning Field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that is partitioned by day using a Timestamp field `my_partition_field` from the schema (and not the ingestion time `_PARTITIONTIME`)

When I execute the following query :

```
SELECT my_partition_field FROM MY_TABLE;
```

BigQuery tells me that **"This query will process XX MB when run"**. The amount of data processed is the same as if the field was not the partitioning field.

However, if I have the same table partitioned by ingestion time and I run the following query :

```
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME FROM MY_TABLE_2;
```

BigQuery tells me that **"This query will process 0 B when run."**

Why is there a difference in the data processed (and billed :) ) between these two cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a partitioned table in BigQuery, your charges are based on how much data is stored in the partitions and on the queries you run against the data[1]. Many partitioned table operations are free as is `_PARTITIONTIME`[2]. There is no difference between the processed data, just the data which is in both tables may be different because, in the time-unit partitioned table, the partition is based on a `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE` or `DATETIME` column in the table. On the other hand, the Ingestion time tables are partitioned based on the timestamp when BigQuery ingests the data.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#pricing

[2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free